# Tag rename request: [excel] -> [microsoft-excel] & [powerpoint] -> [microsoft-powerpoint]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tags

> **This question has been superseded by [Can we please standardize the Microsoft tags?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/can-we-please-standardize-the-microsoft-tags).**

<sub>At the time of writing this, there are 722 questions tagged as [excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel) & 161 questions tagged as [powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint)</sub>

<sub>I propose that the tag [excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel) be renamed to [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) and [powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint) to [microsoft-powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint) considering the questions on Microsoft Word & Microsoft Access are tagged with [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) prefixes.</sub>

Comment: +1 I think this makes sense in terms of maintaining consistency. Thinking aloud: "Word" and "Access" on their own (as a tag) *could* be misconstruced is something else computer related, so they *need* the prefix. However, I *think* there's only one valid use of "Excel" and "Powerpoint", in computing terms, which is probably why ended up without.

Comment: @DMA5736 - Yup, that's right.

Comment: @Hello thanks for the edit; it was an (unnoticed) typo.

Answer (score 2):

This was a huge mistake.  There's no reason to create those huge tags, when the small ones were understandable by everyone.  The non-microsoft tags have worked fine on SO for the last few years without confusion for excel and powerpoint.  Access is ms-access and word is split between msword and word (on SO).  It makes no sense to just make them bigger and more cumbersome, and it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Apparently there are Microsoft fanbois as well

Comment: Over a long period of time you are the first one to mention this.

Comment: @Tom, yep, the Meta sites for anything but SO get very little traffic.  Excel and VBA are my main tags, so I care a lot about them.

Comment: Yes, but it's 2 upvotes here against the 9 upvotes on the question that superseded the previous questions; in these 4 questions nobody complained about it until now... Google also reveals that people more likely type Microsoft X than MS X.

Comment: @Tom, because of the delay in time for this answer, I don't expect the upvotes.  I think you'll find more people search for just __Excel__, which is what you'd do on SO.

Comment: But we're not SO, and while that may apply to Excel, it doesn't apply to all others...