# Can we please standardize the Microsoft tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, retagging

Tags for Microsoft products are currently a mess.

Office:

- <s>[office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office)</s>, [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office)
- <s>[office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2007)</s>, <s>[office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2010)</s>, [office-2010-beta](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2010-beta), <s>[ms-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-2007)</s>, [office-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2008), [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010), [office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2010), [office-1997](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-1997) <sub>(wow...)</sub>, <s>[office-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2002)</s>, <s>[ms-office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-2003)</s>, <s>[office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2003)</s>

Word:

- [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word), <s>[msword](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msword)</s>, <s>[word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word)</s>
- [microsoft-word-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2007), [microsoft-word-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2010), [microsoft-word-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2003), [microsoft-word-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2008)
- <s>[word-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2007), [word-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2003)</s>

Excel:

- [excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel), [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)
- [excel-formula](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula)
- [excel-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2003), [excel-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2007), [excel-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2010), <s>[excel-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2002)</s>

Powerpoint:

- <s>[powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint)</s>, [microsoft-powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint)
- [powerpoint-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2007), [powerpoint-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2010), [powerpoint-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2003)
- <s>[powerpoint-video](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-video)</s>

Publisher:

- [microsoft-publisher](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-publisher)

Access:

- <s>[access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access)</s>, [microsoft-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access), [ms-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-access)
- [microsoft-access-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access-2007), [microsoft-access-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access-2003)

There is very little structure or order in how Microsoft-related questions are being tagged. I think this should be cleaned up. I would like to propose the following tagging recommendations for office questions; feel free to critique my suggestions.

- Questions about a **specific microsoft product**, like Word, should be tagged like [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word).
- Questions that pertain to a **specific version of office**, and would *not apply* to all/other versions, should be tagged like [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010)
- Questions pertaining to **any or many versions of office** should be tagged [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office)

A question could have several of these tags, e.g. it might be tagged [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010) and [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) if the question is about Word and is specific to the 2010 version. While more verbose than just [microsoft-word-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2010), it creates fewer redundant tags.

Tags above which do not fall into one of those categories/naming schemes should be retagged and eliminated, <s>with the following exceptions</s>:

- <s>[word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word) might apply to some other things having to do with words, but posts with that tag should be manually checked and retagged if appropriate.</s>
- <s>[office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office) might apply to questions about office environments. Those sorts of questions should be retagged to [home-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-office) or something of that sort</s>
- <s>[access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access) might apply to questions about access control, etc. Those sorts of questions should be retagged to a more appropriate tag, as `access` is ambiguous.</s>

Most of this retagging should be able to be accomplished by moderators automatically with a batch retag, e.g. [ms-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-2007) to [microsoft-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2007). More nuanced ones, like <s>the exceptions above</s> [paint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/paint) and similar, will need to be handled manually; I can do this if need be.

So, do these seem like reasonable suggestions?
What changes would you recommend? And how can we try to encourage new users to tag accordingly?

Comment: A quick comment regarding moving the version numbers to the `office` tag -- users who don't know about any consensus reached here (ie, almost all of them) will (for example) instinctively enter `word-2007` as a tag, and not `word` + `office-2007`. I don't see a sensible way to avoid this issue using the available tools (ie, synonyms), thoughts? What's the problem with just having the `word-2007` tag on a question, the fact the question is about office is implicit anyway.

Comment: [Tag rename request: `excel` -> `microsoft-excel` & `powerpoint` -> `microsoft-powerpoint`](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1654/tag-rename-request-excel-microsoft-excel-powerpoint-microsoft-pow)

Comment: It's on my to-do list, but I need to explore the tagged questions before taking it up @nhinkle

Comment: Thanks Sathya. @DMA57361, at the very least we don't need to have `word-2007` and `microsoft-word-2007` and `ms-word-2007`. Is there any mechanism for having something be a synonym of two tags, i.e. `word-2007` be automatically changed to `microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word`?

Comment: @nhinkle AFAIK synonyms are a single change only, not a split. And I agree that a single version of each "version" tag is needed, but I still personally prefer a single "version" tag over a `office-version + word` pair.

Comment: @DMA57361 that seems reasonable.

Comment: @DMA57361, @sathya it looks like right now `microsoft-powerpoint` is being changed to `powerpoint`, while others are being remapped the other way. Can these be made consistent, too?

Comment: @nhinkle good point, and I've inverted the synonym and merged `powerpoint` to `microsoft-powerpoint`

Comment: @TomWij, while the post you marked as a dupe does cover similar ground, this post does have tags yours didn't, and proposes a new method of organizing the tags, rather than just listing them. As such, I don't believe it needs to be closed as dupe.

Comment: Thanks @dma57351

Comment: Regarding why we might save `[word]`, I think that outside the context of Microsoft Office, it would be considered a meta tag and should be removed as such.  Same should apply to `[access]` as there are more specific uses for "access" such as `[acl]` which would be better suited.

Comment: @nhinkle: My post also did, but deleted that and spent some effort to embed **everything** properly under **[this answer](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/can-we-please-standardize-the-microsoft-tags/2112#2112)** to ease the process for the moderators. Did some manual progress but we still need to do [paint] and [word]... :-)

Answer (score 25):

### Vote: Microsoft or MS?

Given that the short versions are ambiguous (access, office, word), let's vote between the other two...

- **Vote up if you want [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft)**, examples given: [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office), [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word)
- **Vote down if you want [ms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms)**, examples given: [ms-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-office), [ms-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-word)
- Versions aren't included in this voting...

Just checking to be sure, most people like [microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), but [ms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms) is shorter (might not be typed well?).

Comment: How do you do the markdown for entering tags in posts by the way?

Comment: @boehj: [tag:microsoft], whenever you need it you can [see the source of a post](http://meta.superuser.com/revisions/5a4867e7-0cc8-4afc-b438-44e067706192/view-source) by clicking on the date/time under the post and then clicking "view source". :)

Answer (score 9):

### Full list of necessary retags:

- **WORD OF CAUTION:** See [the list of tags Scheduled for Manual Progress](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/standardize-microsoft-office-tags/2109#2109).
- **Microsoft Access, any/many versions:**

  - <s>[ms-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) --> [microsoft-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access)</s>
- **Microsoft Excel, specific versions:**

  - <s>[excel-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2002) --> [microsoft-excel-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2002)</s>
  - <s>[excel-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2003) --> [microsoft-excel-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2003)</s>
  - <s>[excel-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2007) --> [microsoft-excel-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2007)</s>
  - <s>[excel-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2010) --> [microsoft-excel-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2010)</s>
- **Microsoft Excel, any/many versions:**

  - <s>[excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel) --> [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)</s>
  - <s>[excel-formula](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) --> [formula](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/formula)</s>
- **Microsoft OneNote, specific versions:** *Done*

  - <s>[onenote-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/onenote-2007) --> [microsoft-onenote-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-onenote-2007)</s>
  - <s>[onenote-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/onenote-2010) --> [microsoft-onenote-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-onenote-2010)</s>
- **Microsoft OneNote, any/many versions:** *Done*

  - <s>[onenote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/onenote) --> [microsoft-onenote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-onenote)</s>
- **Microsoft Outlook, any/many versions:**

  - <s>[outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook) --> [microsoft-outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook)</s>
  - <s>[outlook-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2003) --> [microsoft-outlook-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook-2003)</s>
  - <s>[outlook-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2007) --> [microsoft-outlook-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook-2007)</s>
  - <s>[outlook-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2010) --> [microsoft-outlook-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook-2010)</s>
- **Microsoft Paint, any/many versions:**

  - [paint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/paint) --> **await manual progress** + [microsoft-paint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-paint)
  - <s>[ms-paint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-paint) --> [microsoft-paint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-paint)   *Done*</s>
- **Microsoft Powerpoint, specific versions:**

  - <s>[powerpoint-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2003) --> [microsoft-powerpoint-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint-2003)</s>
  - <s>[powerpoint-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2007) --> [microsoft-powerpoint-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint-2007)</s>
  - <s>[powerpoint-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2010) --> [microsoft-powerpoint-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint-2010)</s>
- **Microsoft Project, specific versions:**

  - <s>[ms-project-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-project-2007) --> [microsoft-project-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-project-2007)</s>
- **Microsoft Security Essentials, any/many versions:**

  - <s>[ms-security-essentials](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-security-essentials) --> [microsoft-security-essentials](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-security-essentials)</s>  - the tag [microsoft-security-essentials](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-security-essentials) **exceeds** the max tag length of 25 chars.
- **Microsoft SQL Server, any/many versions:**

  - [ms-sql](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-sql) --> [microsoft-sql-sever](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-sql-sever)
- **Microsoft Visio, specific version:**

  - <s>[visio-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visio-2007) --> [microsoft-visio-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-visio-2007)</s>
  - <s>[visio-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visio-2010) --> [microsoft-visio-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-visio-2010)</s>
- **Microsoft Visio, any/many versions:**

  - <s>[visio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visio) --> [microsoft-visio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-visio)</s>
- **Microsoft Word, specific versions:**

  - <s>[word-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2003) --> [microsoft-word-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2003)</s>
  - <s>[word-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2007) --> [microsoft-word-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2007)</s>
- **Microsoft Word, any/many versions:**

  - <s>[word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word) --> **await manual progress** + [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word)</s>
  - <s>[msword](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msword) --> [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word)</s>
- **Microsoft Office, specific versions:**

  - <s>[office-1997](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-1997) --> [microsoft-office-1997](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-1997) + close as **too localized**, perhaps delete.</s>
  - <s>[office-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2002) --> [microsoft-office-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2002)</s>
  - <s>[office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2003) --> [microsoft-office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2003)</s>
  - <s>[office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2007) --> [microsoft-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2007)</s>
  - <s>[office-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2008) --> [microsoft-office-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2008)</s>
  - <s>[office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2010) --> [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010)</s>
  - <s>[office-2010-beta](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2010-beta) --> [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010) + close as **too localized**, perhaps delete.</s>
  - <s>[ms-office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-2003) --> [microsoft-office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2003)</s>
  - <s>[ms-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-office-2007) --> [microsoft-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2007)</s>

Comment: did the Microsoft-Onenote tags and the ms-paint tag.

Comment: Except for SQL Server, I completed all the remaining merges and synonymizations.

Answer (score 4):

### Consensus?

Given that already six people upvoted the question, can we perform the retagging?

As [@nhinkle said](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2100/9666), adjusted to match [@DMA57351's note](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/standardize-microsoft-office-tags#comment-4405), example retaggings with Word & 2010:

> - **Specific microsoft product, specific version:** [word-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2010) --> [microsoft-word-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2010).
> - **Specific microsoft product, any/many versions**: [word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word) --> [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word).
> - **Microsoft Office, specific version:** [office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2010) --> [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010)
> - **Microsoft Office, any/many versions:** [office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office) --> [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office)

As for this quote from [@nhinkle's question](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2100/9666):

> And how can we try to encourage new users to tag accordingly?

Synonyms solve this problem, so it's important that they are made where they fit to prevent issues.

**WORD OF CAUTION:** Manual retaggings are still necesarry for some tags, check the [Manual Progress](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/standardize-microsoft-office-tags/2109#2109).

Answer (score 3):

### Manual Progress

The [access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/access), [office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office) and [paint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/paint) questions have all been retagged. :-)

<sub>Removed [remote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote) tags in the progress where they that had more specific tags, we also might want [speed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speed) --> [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance).</sub>

### Scheduled for Manual Progress

- <s>We still need to do [word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word), which seems quite a bit of work...</s>

Comment: Several moderators actually. Mainly because flooding with retags does a lot to drown out the rest of questions.

Comment: Yes, @random, but **manual** work can't be done automatically. And I try to minimize this work to non-busy times and as much as possible so that the impact is minimal, furthermore, a simple retag shouldn't cause a global site bump but instead only the activity seen in the moderator tools...

Comment: @TomWij - why not? "Manual" work is currently poorly defined - for example where you manually renamed `[word-2003]` -> `[microsoft-word-2003]`, we could of done that in a single transparent action with no flooding. And, ideally, we need synonyms to go with these changes or the old tags will just re-appear later.

Comment: @TomWij, `[hardware]` and `[software]` should have been blacklisted/banned. I don't see a place for me to do this, however, might be a dev level thing, or I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: However, @DMA57361, that is not true for the majority of questions covered by office, access, remote which can only be re-tagged by manual work. The amount of questions covered by the other tags were arbitrary small, those small re-tags are equivalent to the normal re-tags people perform and didn't show up any flooding behavior at all. Furthermore; the more popular tags [hardware] & [software] return too which still requires manual removal. The tags you mentioned are now listed too and no longer considered manual work.

Comment: I didn't say there was *no* manual work, I said the term was poorly defined. *Any* case where every Q with a given tag need the same action should probably be able to be handled automatically, if a tag has a case-by-case effect to take in to account then yes it probably needs hitting manually.

Comment: @DMA576361: I don't see why **manual** work is poorly defined, it's simply the things a moderator can't do, as [quack quixote covers in his comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46729/system-to-minimize-the-soft-problems-due-to-manual-retagging/46755#comment-107977) on the related meta question...

Comment: A poor turn of phrase perhaps. My point was that by your original post you had manually done something with word-2003, word-2007, office-2002 and excel-2002, all of which was unnecessary - they should just have had synonyms created and merged into the microsoft- variants.

Comment: I don't see why simple retags that are bumped away anyway are unnecessary other than to *wait* for the moderators to do the same, [they have been listed](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/can-we-please-standardize-the-microsoft-tags/2112#2112) so there is no real problem? Whether I add such simple retags or not will not result in any difference on the frontpage, for example, if I didn't do the simple retags then my manual retags would be listed at the bottom of the frontpage. So, in essence, no difference in flooding and no difference in moderator work, so I don't see the real problem?

Comment: Retagging where ambiguous is fine. Retagging batches which could have easily been done with merges (especially of versions where you only add an extra word for the sake of something), where no ambiguity exists is best handled by moderators. The recent flooding appears to be more of the latter.

Comment: By the way @TomWij, regarding "We still need to do `[word]`, which seems quite a bit of work..." - `[word]` is a synonym (to `[microsoft-word]` since October) and as such doesn't have any posts linked to it... what work is there to be done?

Comment: @random: I see otherwise, I've mostly done [access], [office] and [remote] which were really too ambiguous to just merge them without intervention.

Comment: @DMA57361: @As nhinkle said, it is indeed a synonym so I'll update...

Comment: @random: This questions me, why is it still not handled by the moderators after 13 people agree on this question? Why do we, the community, have to do this manually to get a sense of consistence? Where is our human exception handler? Where is the moderator team's reasoning on the recent excel merge? Can you elaborate [on this meta question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2786/why-are-changes-applied-without-any-reasoning-or-community-agreement) because I don't get the point and am starting to get confused as I'm sure we are supposed to be a community?