# Please align the Excel tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

We lost the battle on [excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel) already, so now it's labeled [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel), but I see there is still confusion with the version specific tags.

[microsoft-excel-2002](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2002)
[microsoft-excel-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2003)    [excel-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2003)
[microsoft-excel-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2007)    [excel-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2007)
[microsoft-excel-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2010)    [excel-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2010) (s)
[excel-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-2011)

Could a moderator please setup tag synonyms and retag so their all the same format, as you can see, only one is setup that way right now.

I'd like to suggest that on the version specific tags, we dump the `microsoft`, since all of these questions should already have the [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) also.  I realize that this would involve changing the existing `2010` synonym around, but I think the cleanup would be worth the trouble.

Note: It gets really crazy when you two or more versions and the canonical tag all together, which is to be expected for these kind of questions, since some of the versions kind of group together for functionality.

Comment: Pretty sure no other company makes a spreadsheet program called Excel, so that request earlier back was needless redundancy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we please standardize the Microsoft tags?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/can-we-please-standardize-the-microsoft-tags)

Comment: -1 @random: The tags should be remapped the other way around for consistency, [we've already reached that consensus earlier](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/can-we-please-standardize-the-microsoft-tags) but the remaps haven't happened until this sudden one which is the other way around of what we wanted to achieve...

Comment: I would agree with @Tom in that case, the other one has had a lot of input and suggestions already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-alignment has been achieved. Your car is now back to roadworthiness. Of a sort.

#### excel-2010

```
updating post history, 126 rows affected
updating posts, 104 rows affected
tag remapping of [excel-2010] and [microsoft-excel-2010] complete!
```

#### excel-2007

```
updating post history, 6 rows affected
updating posts, 3 rows affected
tag remapping of [excel-2007] and [microsoft-excel-2007] complete!
Tag Synonym microsoft-excel-2007 -> excel-2007 was approved!
```

#### excel-2003

```
updating post history, 4 rows affected
updating posts, 3 rows affected
tag remapping of [excel-2003] and [microsoft-excel-2003] complete!
Tag Synonym microsoft-excel-2003 -> excel-2003 was approved!
```

#### excel-2002

```
updating post history, 7 rows affected
updating posts, 3 rows affected
tag remapping of [excel-2002] and [microsoft-excel-2002] complete!
Tag Synonym microsoft-excel-2002 -> excel-2002 was approved!
```

Comment: The comment thread here has been moved to a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/624/discussion-between-tom-wijsman-and-lance-roberts).