# Can we rename "window" to "gui-window"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

When I was looking around in the [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag (while waiting for an answer...) I noticed that many people when they were talking about the Windows OS, they tagged it both with [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [window](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/window).

**I do realise that there may be some overlap.** For example, if someone is talking about a GUI-window *in* the Windows OS. Many people think that they are the same thing... why cannot we change them to "windows-os" and "gui-window"?

Comment: I don't even see a point in the window tag to be honest.

Comment: `windows-os` looks weird. `microsoft-windows` perhaps, and make `windows` a synonym? (How could we [fix all the other important Microsoft tags and not consider Windows?!](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2100))

Comment: @DanielBeck Now that you say that it looks like an echo... *Windows-ndows-os*. Anyway, I just want to remove this confusion so it is easier to find tagged questions. Can we rename tags because it would just be best to do [tag:microsoft-windows] because some people who are talking about GUI windows in Linux or Mac OS X might still refer to it as "widnows." Plus, if they were to type in "windows" in the tag field it would still show both (try editing this page with "request" in the tags for [tag:feature-request] and see what happens... but don't save the edit it obviously.)

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Yes, tags can be renamed, and we can also define synonyms -- if a user e.g. insists on using the tag `excel`, it gets rewritten as `microsoft-excel`. Synonyms also shows up in the tag suggestions popup, try typing e.g. `pro` into the tags field on the main site and see what gets suggested. So I'd just make `windows` a tag synonym of `microsoft-windows` then, similar to how `word` is a tag synonym of `microsoft-word`, as long as my [disambiguation feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags) isn't implemented…

Comment: @DanielBeck I understand that I just feel like that if someone is just typing windows meaning the GUI and they were already ignorant to see that it says "the Microsoft operating system..." or whatever if its a synonym they probably won't notice it changing to "microsoft-windows." Just search "windows" (no tags at all) and on the first few pages they'll be plenty of people who mistagged it. If they can't see that it says *Microsoft* in the wiki I don't think that they will notice it change.