# Rename [tv] -> [television]

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

Super User has a [tv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tv) tag; its wiki says “television”. 
I suggest that the tag be *renamed* [television](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/television), and “tv” added as an alias. 
This would seem to fit better with the [convention](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2100/150988)
of making the actual tag name be the real, full name of the thing,
and relegating abbreviations to aliases.

Answer (score 3):

I like the proposal. [tv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tv) makes me also think of [teamviewer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/teamviewer).