# Time to [exchange] with [microsoft-exchange]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

In 2011, Microsoft products were retagged to include Microsoft in the tag title. (See *'[Can we please standardize the Microsoft tags?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2100/can-we-please-standardize-the-microsoft-tags)'*)

Because of this, we have consistently named tags for [microsoft-office](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office), [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel), [microsoft-word](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word), [microsoft-visio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-visio), [microsoft-powerpoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint), [microsoft-outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook), and [microsoft-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-access).

Ironically, we somehow managed to miss retagging the most potentially confusing Microsoft tag.

**I propose retagging [exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exchange) and all its versions as [microsoft-exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-exchange) both for consistency, and to prevent confusion with the Stack Exchange network.**

Comment: Are you also proposing we rename all the version ones too?

Comment: @Burgi I see no reason why not. Super User already does the same for [microsoft-office-2010], [microsoft-word-2010], [microsoft-excel-2010], [microsoft-powerpoint-2010], [microsoft-access-2010], [microsoft-outlook-2010], and [microsoft-visio-2010]